# SQLAlchemy load multiple orm models in a single query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to load results from a **single query** and have the **rows mapped to different models** depending on some condition?

### Context

My use case:

- perform full-text search across two tables,
- rank the results,
- paginate the *combined* result with OFFSET/LIMIT.

### Example

Ignoring the search aspect for simplicity's sake, let's assume these tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE blogposts (
    id           integer PRIMARY KEY,
    body         varchar,
    search_rank  real
);
CREATE TABLE comments (
    id           integer PRIMARY KEY,
    body         varchar,
    search_rank  real
);
```

With some sample rows:

```sql
INSERT INTO blogposts VALUES (1, 'foo', 0.2);
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (1, 'bar', 1.2);
```

And these declarative models:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Float, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class Blogpost(Base):
    __tablename__ = "blogposts"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = Column(String)
    search_rank = Column(Float)


class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = "comments"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = Column(String)
    search_rank = Column(Float)
```

In SQL, I can UNION results from both tables and rank/paginate them like so:

```
SELECT 'blogpost' AS type, id, search_rank FROM blogposts
UNION
SELECT 'comment' AS type, id, search_rank FROM comments
ORDER BY search_rank DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 100

/* =>
   type   | id | search_rank
----------+----+-------------
 comment  |  1 |         1.2
 blogpost |  1 |         0.2
(2 rows)
*/
```

With SQLAlchemy I can also get raw results:

```py
results = (
    session.query(
        literal("blogpost").label("type"),
        Blogpost.id,
        Blogpost.search_rank.label("search_rank")
    )
    .union(session.query(
        literal("comment").label("type"),
        Comment.id,
        Comment.search_rank.label("search_rank")
    ))
    .order_by(text("search_rank desc"))
    .offset(0)
    .limit(100)
    .all()
)
results
# => [('comment', 1, 1.2), ('blogpost', 1, 0.2)]
```

### Question

Is there a SQLAlchemy `Query` construct I can use to get these mapped to `Blogpost`/`Comment` instances?